# Как получить file_id в боте на aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

у меня есть бот
в нем через машину состояний надо отправить квитанцию об оплате
потом бот должен получить id фотографии и переотправить ее админам
вот код:

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text_contains="confim", state=None)
async def choise_st2_handler(call: CallbackQuery):
    chat = call.message.chat.id
    msg = call.message.message_id
    uid = call.data.split("-")[1]
    add_pay(chat,uid,"None")
    await call.answer(cache_time=5)
    await call.bot.edit_message_text('Ок, Тепеь отправьте квитанцию оплаты в этот чат', chat, msg)
    await get_screen.message.set()

@dp.message_handler(state=get_screen.message)
async def scan_message(msg: types.Message):
    photo_id = msg.photo[-1].file_id
    await bot.send_photo(chat_id=chat, photo=photo_id)
```

но тут появляется такая проблема, он просто не видит эти картинки
зато есть отправить ему текст он выбивает ошибку
что делать?

Comment: Выложите весь код и конкретный текст ошибки, непонятно, что происходит до этого и во время ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

У меня  сработало. Пересылка фотографии админу.

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=ContentType.PHOTO)
async def get_file_id_p(message: Message):
    await message.reply("Фотография отправлена Администрации на обработку")
    # await message.reply(message.photo[-1].file_id)
    await bot.send_photo([Admin ID], message.photo[-1].file_id)
```